# How to solve the beep sound problem on linux?

Tags: linux-mint, audio, echo

Currently I am using Linux mint. I tried the following command on the command line.

```
echo -e  "\a"
```

As we know this command should produce a beep sound, but on my Linux machine nothing happened, it did not produce any sound.

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Does this help you [Beep in shell script not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19906/beep-in-shell-script-not-working)?

Comment: This question needs to state what terminal was being used, because why the terminal bell might not be working varies from one terminal type to another.  Sound problems with the built-in terminal emulator for KVTs in Linux will be of a different nature to sound problems with (say) Unicode rxvt.

Answer (score 1):

1-login with root 
2-Find out what TTY is yours(write w in terminal, and press Enter) 
3-I suppose your TTY is TTY1(means: /dev/TTY1)
4-echo -e "\a" >/dev/tty1

now you should hear beep !

Answer (score 0):

On my Arch / Gnome installation, disabling System Sounds in Settings kills the Terminal Beep as well; upon allowing them your command line worked for me through the system sounds (not through the motherboard "buzzer").

Comment: How can i enable system sound